# My saveas code creates a file that needs to be repaired

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code:

```
Sub saveAsXlsx()
    Dim myPath As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Worksheets(Array("User")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "\VUONGJO.xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Pretty simple stuff.  Saves an .xlsm as a .xlsx file

The information is correct that is saved.  The only problem is when you open the .xlsx it says repairs to the file and lists:

Removed Feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

but when I to use ActiveWorkbook.Cells.Validation.Delete it doesnt work.

I dont want the valadation removed from the original, but I want to save a copy without it, im stumped

Comment: Are you opening in a different version of excel than the version used to run this macro? Also, what is `Worksheets(Array("User")).Copy` doing here?

Comment: Specify the file format in the saveas method XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Comment: Also, try, removing the data validation from the original, saving the file, adding it back in and re-running. Sometimes there's some corruption in the file that causes these issues. If this or other comments don't work, try re-building workbook from scratch. (I had to go that route recently).

Comment: The array user part is because I'm copying the info on a sheet in an xlsm and I'm trying to save the information as an xlsx

Comment: Actually though,  its not a code problem your questions and suggestions just helped me figure it out.  I need the conditional formatting list referenced in the newly copied file not just the worksheet with the data on it